# --with-sysroot is not honored during a compile on OS X?

Tags: c++, ios, cross-compiling, autoconf

I have a C++ project. I am testing a cross-compile with Autotools on OS X for iOS. I configure with:

```
$ echo $IOS_SYSROOT
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk

$ CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -arch arm64" ./configure --with-sysroot="$IOS_SYSROOT" --build=`config.guess` --host=aarch64-ios
```

When `make`'ing it results in (line breaks added for clarity):

```
libtool: compile:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. ... -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -arch arm64 -MT adhoc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/adhoc.Tpo -c adhoc.cpp -o adhoc.o
In file included from adhoc.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:44:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++config.h:41:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/os_defines.h:61:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:658:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
...
```

Notice the wrong header files are being used. The build system's headers are used rather than the iPhone headers. I'm fairly certain `--with-sysroot` is not being honored. Searching for the keywords seems to indicate its a [widespread problem with Autoconf](https://www.google.com/search?q=autoconf+"--with-sysroot") (based on all the bug reports trying to use the feature).

Manually adding `CXXFLAGS="-sysroot=$IOS_SYSROOT -arch arm64 ...` seems to fix the issue. This seems to be the same problem (or nearly the same problem) detailed at [Bug 79885: --with-build-sysroot= does not get honored throughout the build](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79885).

There does not seem to be a `AC_SYSROOT` (or similar) to copy `--with-sysroot` into `AM_CXXFLAGS`. Searching the Autoconf site for the keywords is not returning useful hits: ["--with-sysroot" site:https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22--with-sysroot%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fsoftware%2Fautoconf%2Fmanual).

How are we supposed to handle Autoconf's `--with-sysroot` option? What is the practice packagers are supposed to follow?

---

Here are the Autoconf prject files: [cryptopp-autotools](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools). There are two files of interest, and they are `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`. I'm not sure what applies to this problem at the moment.

Here's the message where Autoconf tells users to use it:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep sysroot
  --with-sysroot[=DIR]    Search for dependent libraries within DIR (or the
                          compiler's sysroot if not specified).
```

I'd prefer to supress the message if Autoconf cannot wire-in `--with-sysroot` properly. Otherwise, users are going to be filling bug reports against us.

Comment: Suggest you export `CXX="clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`. It looks like it's defaulting to the legacy 'gcc' headers from the gcc/clang transition era.